# How do I hit my web app over the Internet?

Tags: ip, portforwarding, glassfish-4

1) Port 80 is open and forwarded to local machine (I can verify it with a port checking tool).

2) Glassfish is running and the web app is deployed (I can see it 192.168.1.3:8080/FamilyTree and it is listed in the admin console)

3) How do I get to the site using my router's external ip address? What do I type?

Is it externalIP/FamilyTree?

I'm probably missing a really simple step but would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are inside your network, you might not be able to.  A lot of routers don't support the local loopback required to go from behind your router->public IP->back to your private network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Port **80** should be opened on router and mapped to your local machine to port **8080**
2. Then you need to find out your external IP address, try http://www.whatismyip.com/
3. then just open browser with http://**YOUR EXTERNAL IP**/FamilyTree

Comment: what does it mean, mapped to my local machine on 8080? port 80 is opened on my router and pointing to my machine's local ip. Do I have to specify 8080 somewhere?

Comment: @user2947084 yes, you need to configure your router to forward requests which are to ROUTER:80 to YOURLOCALIP:8080

Comment: perhaps you need to have glashfish running on 80 if you are forwarding 80 and can't change which local port it points at.  Or you could open port 8080 and forward that to your local machine.

Comment: Ok, so I set my router to forward 80 to 8080 but I couldn't hit 8080 with port check tool. Created an inbound rule in the firewall/turned firewall off...etc.

Comment: Put the router back to forward 80 to 80, port is showing as open, so now I'll try having glassfish listen on 80.

Comment: Followed the instructions per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045897/how-to-run-glassfish-4-on-port-80-instead-of-8080-root-acess-is-not-an-issue

...and nothing...set http_listener1 to 80 on both default config and server config

Comment: try to setup both ports to be 8080, check that data is forwarded to proper LOCALIP and ask some friend to hit you via internet (to avoid problems like @Joe mentioned in comments), as soon as both ports are 8080 - you need to open `http://EXTERNALIP:8080/` - enter full protocol and address

Comment: I don't seem to be able to forward 8080 on my router. What I have currently is port 80 forwarded to internal port 80. 80 is showing as open on my machine. I can hit glassfish locally using 192.168.1.3:80/FamilyTree (where of course the 80 isn't necessary). To Joe's point, when I try to hit the server using the external ip from my phone (using 4G), I get a timeout.

Comment: @user2947084 seems like problem with router, either it has port forwarding or not, if has - then you will be able to configure it

Comment: Well a system restart fixed it! I can now see the site! My hunch is the port checking tool I was using was interfering...reason being, I installed a wamp server to see if I could get that up and when I did "put online", the port checking tool told me 80 wasn't available (yeah, because it was in use by the server!!!!)  I think the same thing was going on with glassfish...the tool, by telling me it was available, had claimed it for itself.