# GlassFish server unable to start in NetBeans IDE 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0 to create Java Web Applictions . It was working perfectly , but today whenever I try to run my project , it displays the error :-

> Could not start GlassFish Server: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is occupied while server is not running See the server log for details.

What can I do to get the server started . I recently installed Oracle XE 10g and this is the first time I opened NetBeans after doing so .

What could be wrong ? Please explain how to resolve this problem with steps.
Immediate help would be appreciated !
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Both GlassFish and Oracle XE 10g uses http 8080 port by default, try changing either of those.

Comment: But how do I do it ? Please help me out !

Answer (score 0):

First Debug that is problem with Oracle xe or not/
Stop oracle xe : if you are using windows 7 directly from programmer file you can stop it
After that start glass Fish server.. if the gF is started successfully that is problem with Oracle XE Start Menu >> Programs >> Oracle Database 10G Express Edition >> stop oracle xe
Then change port of oracle xe

from cmd give this

```
CONNECT system
admin
BEGIN
DBMS_XDB.sethttpport('9090');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need Oracle running then you can change the port that Glassfish uses - see the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415279/823393).

Answer (score 0):

Even mine case was the same. What I did to get the problem fixed was as::

Find the program(it's PID) which is using port on which GlassFish Server will run(default 1527). To do so use command `netstat -ano | find "1527"`. Now find the details about given process and stop the services related to it. In mine case it was Oracle Database services. Disable them from there if they are not required. Else if you can't disable the services( assuming they are important) you can make GlassFish server to open on a different port by editing it's  `domain.xm` file located inside Glassfish installation folders.

```
  <network-listener port="1527" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
```

Change 1527 to other port which is free.

Hope this fixed your problem.

Happy Coding :)