# Can I have apache and glassfish running on one server machine?

Tags: apache, server, glassfish

There's a physical server machine with apache running on it, some apps deployed there. I'm gonna need a glassfish server. Is it possible to set it up on that machine and have both apache and glassfish running simultaneously? If yes, then what problems could that cause?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Normally this shouldn't cause problems, because Glassfish is running on port 8080 per default and Apache is running on port 80 and 443.

If your Apache is configured to run on port 8080 this won't work or you have to change the default port of your Glassfish server.

**See also:**

- [How to run glassfish 4 on port 80 instead of 8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045897/how-to-run-glassfish-4-on-port-80-instead-of-8080-root-acess-is-not-an-issue)
- [Binding to Addresses and Ports - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html)